# Script Editor / Files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I just divided my 1800 line project into 12 'Files' within the Spreadsheet Script Editor.  I noticed that the Find function only looks within the active File.

Is there anyway to do a global find ?

Also related to Files within a Project, when errors are thrown, a line number is referenced but not the File name.

Is there a way to determine which File contains the line that caused the error ?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do a global find. Find will only look in the current file. I agree that there should be a find and replace that would transverse the entire project and I filed and issue back in September 2011, in the Issue Tracker at:

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=822

Please go there and star it to vote it up and be notified of any progress on this issue.

The issue of no file name being reported with error messages has also been raised in the Issue Tracker at:

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=747

Comment: Thank you ScampMichael !  I starred both.

Answer (score 2):

To determine the file that caused the error you have to try-catch the error and parse the stacktrace. Here is what I do:

```js
function yourCallingfunction() {
  try {
    //do your thing
  } catch(err) {
    stack = parseErr_(err)
    Logger.log(stack);
    throw stack;
  }
}

//Try to parse errors stacktrace into a nicer format
function parseErr_(e) {
  var ret;
  if( e !== undefined && e !== null && e.stack ) {
    ret = e.name +': '+e.message+' \nStacktrace: \n';
    var stack = e.stack.replace(/\n/g,'').match(/:\d+( \([^\)]+\))?/g);
    for( var i in stack )
      ret += stack[i].replace(/[\(\):]/g,'').split(/ /).reverse().join(':') + ' \n';
  } else
    ret = e;
  return ret;
}
```

About the global find, if your issue is only find, not replace, there's a workaround too. Take a look at this:

```js
function showMe() {
  for( var i in this )
    Logger.log(this[i].toString());
}
```

But non of this are actual solutions. You should star the issues linked by @ScampMichael

Comment: This is some very interesting code, thank you Henrique!  I learned a lot from these few lines of code. I starred the two issues that relate to this.

Comment: @Henrique why do you 'throw stack' and not throw the err you caught?

Comment: @PeterHerrmann so I do not have to open the script log to see the stack. It's just right there on the message. Naturally that only do this on the last function on the stack when I have nothing else to do with the error. In my triggers and "finished" scripts, I usually just email it to me, plus all current state I can get.